# Spark 2.3: Reading dataframe inside rdd.map()

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I want to iterate through each row of an RDD using `.map()` and I want to use a dataframe inside the map function as follows:

```scala
val rdd = ...  // rdd holding seq of ids in each row
val df = ...   // df with columns `id: String` and `value: Double`

rdd
  .map { case Row(listOfStrings: Seq[String]) =>
    listOfStrings.foldLeft(Seq[Double]())(op = (temp, curr) => {
      // calling df here
      val extractValue: Double = df.filter(s"id == $curr").first()(1) 
      temp :+ extractValue
    }
  }
```

Above is pseudocode which I made up, and this results in an exception because I cannot call a dataframe inside `.map()`.

The only way I can think of overcoming this is to collect `df` before `.map()` so that it is no longer a dataframe. Is there a method in which I can do this without collecting? Note that joining the rdd and df is not suitable.

Comment: "joining the rdd and df is not suitable" - may I ask why? A join is probably the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have a RDD of lists of IDs `RDD[Seq[String]]` and a dataframe of tuples `(id, value)`. You are trying to replace the IDs of the RDD by the corresponding values in the dataframe.

The way you try to do it is impossible in spark. You cannot reference a dataframe nor a RDD inside a `map`. Indeed, they are objects that you manipulate in the driver to parallelize jobs, executed by the workers. However, the code inside `map` is executed by a worker and a worker cannot delegate work to other workers. Only the driver can. This is why (intuitively) what you are trying to do is not possible.

You say that a join is not suitable. I am not sure why but this is exactly what I propose, in combination with a `flatMap`. I use the RDD API but we could write similar code using the dataframe API.

```scala
// generating data
val data = Seq(Seq("a", "b", "c"), Seq("d", "e"), Seq("f"))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
val df = Seq("a" -> 1d, "b" -> 2d, "c" -> 3d,
             "d" -> 4d, "e" -> 5d, "f" -> 6d)
    .toDF("id", "value")

// Transforming the dataframe into a RDD[String, Double]
val rdd_df = df.rdd
    .map(row => row.getAs[String]("id") -> row.getAs[Double]("value"))


val result = rdd
    // We start with zipWithUniqueId to remember how the lists were arranged
    .zipWithUniqueId
    // we flatten the lists, remembering for each row the list id 
    .flatMap{ case (ids, unique_id) => ids.map(id => id -> unique_id) }
    .join(rdd_df)
    .map{ case(_, (unique_id, value)) => unique_id -> value }
    // we reform the lists by grouping by list id
    .groupByKey
    .map(_._2.toArray)
```

```
scala> result.collect
res: Array[Array[Double]] = Array(Array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0), Array(4.0, 5.0), Array(6.0))
```